# ORDER BY CASE WHEN Alphabetically

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to order a query based on i18n keys I have on memory.
So I built this query:

```
SELECT  "workflow_tasks".* FROM "workflow_tasks"
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN type='Workflow::Tasks::EmailCloseBrothersAboutPersonalDetailsChange' THEN 'Email Close Brothers'
WHEN type='Workflow::Tasks::CaptureFinanceProposal' THEN 'Record Finance Status'
WHEN type='Workflow::Tasks::SubmitCreditCheck' THEN 'Submit Credit Check'
WHEN type='Workflow::Tasks::UpdateDriverBankDetail' THEN 'Update Driver''s Bank Details'
WHEN type='Workflow::Tasks::UpdateDriverPersonalDetail' THEN 'Update Driver''s Personal Details'
WHEN type='Workflow::Tasks::ValidateInsuranceCertificate' THEN 'Validate Driver''s Insurance Certificate'
END
```

I expected it to give me an alphabetical list of tasks based on the string that follows `THEN`

The order is almost correct, except that `ValidateInsuranceCertificate` comes before `UpdateDriverPersonalDetails`. I must've misunderstood the usage of `CASE` in `ORDER BY`:
[image]

Comment: One thing that might make this clearer is to use numbers instead of alpha. `THEN 0` `THEN 1` etc. At least clears up the intention some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your query describing `type`.

You have:

```
WHEN type='Workflow::Tasks::UpdateDriverBankDetail'
```

But the type in your database screenshot is plural. So you should have:

```
WHEN type='Workflow::Tasks::UpdateDriverBankDetails'
```

There might be more typos, but the screenshot truncates the data.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are somehow not getting an exact match.  I would start with:

```
SELECT wf.*,
       (CASE WHEN type = 'Workflow::Tasks::EmailCloseBrothersAboutPersonalDetailsChange' THEN 'Email Close Brothers'
             WHEN type = 'Workflow::Tasks::CaptureFinanceProposal' THEN 'Record Finance Status'
             WHEN type = 'Workflow::Tasks::SubmitCreditCheck' THEN 'Submit Credit Check'
             WHEN type = 'Workflow::Tasks::UpdateDriverBankDetail' THEN 'Update Driver''s Bank Details'
             WHEN type = 'Workflow::Tasks::UpdateDriverPersonalDetail' THEN 'Update Driver''s Personal Details'
             WHEN type = 'Workflow::Tasks::ValidateInsuranceCertificate' THEN 'Validate Driver''s Insurance Certificate'
         END) as sortkey
FROM "workflow_tasks" wf
ORDER BY sortkey;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the reply.
There's a typo on your from clause (wf instead of wt).
But still the same result, V comes before U for some reason.